# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой вызванной библиотекой sstream

Tags: c++

вот код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class DynArray {
private:
    int size;
    double *mass;
public:
    DynArray() : size(0), mass(0) {}
    DynArray(const DynArray &a) : size(a.size), mass(new double[a.size]){
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++) mass[i] = a.mass[i];
    }
    void add(const double &num) {
        double *p=new double[size+1]; 
        memcpy(p,mass,sizeof(double)*size); 
        p[size]=num; 
        delete[] mass; 
        mass=p; 
        size++;
    }
    double get(const int &n) {
        return mass[n];
    }
    DynArray& operator=(const DynArray &d){
        double *p = new double[d.size];
        for(int i=0; i < d.size; i++)
            p[i] = d.mass[i];
        delete[] mass;
        size = d.size;
        mass = p;
        return *this;
    }
    int sizeOf() {return size;}
    ~DynArray(){delete[] mass;}
};

bool isDouble(const string &a){
    int aI=0;
    for(int i=0; i < a.length(); i++){
        if(i < a.length() && a[i] == '.') aI++;
    }
    if(aI > 1) return false;
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++) {
            if(a[i] == '.') continue;
            else if(a[i] < '0' || a[i] > '9') return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool arrayIsDouble (stringstream s){
    while(!s.eof()){
        string buff;
        s >> buff;
        if(!isDouble(buff)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

DynArray parseDynArray (stringstream &s){
    DynArray dA;
    while(!s.eof()){
        double buff;
        s >> buff;
        dA.add(buff);
    }
    return dA;
}

stringstream readFromFile(ifstream &ifs){
    char buff[1000];
    ifs.getline(buff, 1000);
    stringstream strstream;
    strstream << buff;
}


int main(){
    ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    stringstream str = readFromFile(ifs);
    DynArray mass;
    if(arrayIsDouble(str)) {
        mass = parseDynArray(str);
    }
    char buff[100];
    ifs.getline(buff, 100);
    for(int i=0; i<mass.sizeOf(); i++){
        cout << mass.get(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << buff << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

В программе я пытаюсь считать с файла массив до символа '\n' дальше считать параметры с помощью которых я должен буду обработать массив. 
Вот такую ошибку выкидывает :

> error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios':cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'

Выкидывает вроде в 4 строчке кода.

Comment: Все равно кидает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка возникает, потому что вы в функции `bool arrayIsDouble (stringstream s)` передаете `s` по значению, то есть пытаетесь создать его копию, но `stringstream` нельзя копировать ([здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010930/5033855) очень подробное объяснение почему, если вкратце — то это бессмысленно). Передавайте по ссылке:

```
bool arrayIsDouble (stringstream& s){
    while(!s.eof()){
        string buff;
        s >> buff;
        if(!isDouble(buff)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

И да, все таки возвращайте что-нибудь из `readFromFile`.